# What is a "car transport agency"?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

What is a "car transport agency" to issue a car in the following paragraph?
What is the difference among it, a moving company, and a truck-rental company like U-haul?

> And yet her eyes filled with surprising tears a few weeks later as she watched me load the Rambler I’d been issued by a car transport agency, carrying a map of America, my handful of newspaper clips, and the $300 I’d earned cataloguing votes in a My Weekly Reader presidential poll.

This is in [this book](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=tSYPVAqJ548C&pg=PA116&lpg=PA116&dq=%22she+watched+me+load+the+Rambler+I%E2%80%99d+been+issued+by+a+car+transport+agency%22&source=bl&ots=wHpnCZKFh1&sig=nkBc0IAFD-eq4oQfvAA-k8XhNi8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjGtbTi-5PKAhWMJ5QKHUN3D_gQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22she%20watched%20me%20load%20the%20Rambler%20I%E2%80%99d%20been%20issued%20by%20a%20car%20transport%20agency%22&f=false).

Comment: It sounds about the same as a car rental company, although I suppose it could differ in that maybe the car is part of a company motor pool. It doesn't strike me as a common phrasing that most native speakers would be familiar with (at least, not in the U.S.).

Comment: I think this might be one of those companies where you drive someone's car across the country for them. It's a cheap way to transport a car because a lot of the drivers are basically doing it as a (free? negative cost?) way to get across country or something.

Answer (score 1):

A "car transport agency" moves your vehicle for you from one location to another, for example, if you purchased a classic car at an auction in Scottsdale, Arizona, and you want it moved to your home in New York State. The best such agencies will load your vehicle into an insulated, climate-controlled enclosed trailer and have a truck haul it to its destination, so that it will neither incur additional mileage nor be damaged or weather-worn in transit.

The next level of service by a car transport agency is to load your car onto a rented, open trailer, cover it with a tarp, and tow the trailer and car using another car or pickup truck wherever you wish.

The cheapest such "agencies," if they can even be called that, simply hire a licensed young person to drive your car to its destination. I believe this is the case in the example you offered.

A "car or truck rental company," like U-Haul, Hertz or Avis, provides you with a vehicle to move yourself or your belongings from one place to another. Some people prefer to rent a car for an extended trip to avoid racking up miles on their personal vehicle, and they return the car to the same rental agency location where they picked it up.

A "moving company" (such as Bekins or United) is generally a company that ships and/or stores your household belongings when you are moving from one part of the country to another. They may hold your belongings until they have a full truck load if you are moving from a relatively small city to another that is many hundreds or thousands of miles away. They will also store your belongings in climate-controlled warehouses if, for instance, you accept a job overseas for a year or two. Moving companies will come to your home and pack your furniture and belongings for you, relieving you of the responsibility of packing things up yourself. A thousand-mile move of a household full of belongings can easily cost upwards of $10,000, although if you are moving because your employer has transferred you to another city, the employer will often cover this cost. Once your belongings arrive at your new home, the moving company will also unpack everything, placing furniture and other items where you wish them to be, and take away all of the boxes, blankets and other packing materials.

A moving company is more expensive than renting a U-Haul or Penske truck and doing it yourself, but it is also much more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

A "Car Transport Agency" is a company that physically moves you vehicle from one place to another such as www.aceconnectautoshipping.com, this normally happens when you are moving from one state to another or if you are buying a vehicle online through EBAY Motors etc.   A moving company is typically related to your household goods like Graebel Van Lines or United Vane Lines, they will come out to pack and ship all of your personal belongings.  A truck rental company like Uhaul or Budget Truck Rentals is where you rent the vehicle but loading and shipping your items is left completely up to you.